# Should I add items to my unit test that are already checked by a static analysis tool?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing

I've been reading 'Test-Driven iOS Development' to brush up on my unit-testing skills. As I read some of the tests, some seem of questionable use. Indeed, there are some tests that duplicate warnings that Clang already issues to the code.

My question is, should I be spending time writing tests to cover these items?

Here's an example:

```
@interface NGAStackOverflowManager : NSObject

@property (weak) id<NGAStackOverflowManagerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

In the book, there is a test to ensure that the delegate conforms to the `NGAStackOverflowManagerDelegate` protocol. As Clang will show warnings when analyzing the calling code, is it worth writing a test specifically for that?

In addition, is it worth writing tests for generated code? Here's an example:

```
@interface Thing : NSObject
@property (readwrite, retain) NSDate * date;
@end

@implementation Thing
@synthesize date;
@end
```

Is it worth testing the implementation of the `date` property since it's made completely of synthesized code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should focus on unit testing particular *business rules* of a particular protocol which your application depends upon. There is no point in verifying technicalities. After all, does it matter whether `class A` conforms to a particular protocol or not, if application doesn't crash and correctly implements required *business logic*? Unit testing is not about testing everything possible, just every unit that is a part of some visible interface.

There is no point in testing `date` property explicitly just for sake of "testing a property". Instead, write unit tests for *business rules* that depend on `date` property. For example, if your class somehow calculates this property, then write tests for particular scenarios and verify correctness of `date`'s value. This way you achieve the following:

- you write less tests, so they're easier to maintain
- you don't lose any coverage:

  - if a property or another technical detail is used by some interface member (directly, or indirectly) it will be tested along
  - if a property is not used by any high level function then what's the point of testing it - it doesn't influence the desired class's behavior. Maybe it should even be removed
- tests are less dependent on internal details, and thus are less fragile

Going back to "conforming to a particular protocol" - this is a known drawback of unit tests, that they are not intended to verify such things. It may be, that for the purpose of some bootstrap process of your application, `class A` is required to conform to a particular protocol and the application won't even start otherwise. That's why you should also have a small number of [Smoke tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing#Software_development) and [Integration tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_test), that additionally make sure that everything works together.

Comment: Thank you. That's where my intuition was leading me, but I thought I'd pose the question to testers more experienced than I.